# LibGDX: How can I access an xml file from core?

Tags: java, android, xml, libgdx

I've got an xml file I need to access(read only) from core. I tried putting it in the Android assets folder since that's shared, but ironically only the desktop version of my app can access it, the Android one doesn't see it at all. "Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath" points to a different location on the Android version. Is there a spot I can store an xml file so I can access it via core?

Comment: Just for my learning, what is this "core" you speak of?

Comment: Use Gdx.files.internal to access it.

Comment: DavidS, when using LibGdx, core is the platform independent section of the code.

Answer (score 0):

create FileHandle object using your file.

FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("data/myfile.xml");

parse that using [XmlReader](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.html), that is in libgdx bundle.